# Laptop shuts-down when power ac is unplugged on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: gnome, power-management, shutdown

I've been searching the web for answers regarding this issue but most are outdated, and don't work for me, I tried to locate`/apps/gnome-power-manager/general` on dconf-editor but it seems that the paths have been relocated, removed or renamed. I'm not too sure what happened to the paths but I can't come across them. I read a blog that recommend to  `de-select the option use_time_for_policy` under the previous path but as I mention I can't find it. On the same blog it said to run: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power 'use-time-for-policy' 'false'` but it still doesn't do the job. I don't know what to do at this point. If you have experienced the same issues or know how to fix this could you guide to troubleshoot this issue?

**I'm running Ubuntu 15.10**

Comment: It's great that you're running Ubuntu 15.10, but it would be even better to know what laptop model you have __;)__

Comment: I figured the system didn't matter since this issue has been happening on several operating systems and computers but, I'm using a DELL Inspiron 14

Comment: It's always possible that it's some battery controller issue or a bad battery.

Answer (score 0):

Hey everyone just an update on this problem, I was able to fixed it. I started to listen closely to the sounds the computer was making every time it would boot up. I noticed the fan would start and then stop completely and the computer started to get hot. What I did was, I opened up my laptop and moved the fan cables interrupting with the fan and it solved the problem. I'm not quite sure why the fan and the heat of the computer can interrupt with the computer not being able to function without being plugged in, but the problem was solved.